# Adding a filter to an Access Form

Tags: microsoft-access

I have an Access DB that tracks all of my students that are going through a certain class i.e. MGMT224 18-01.  I have built a filter that already sorts the class numbers and the student numbers for me that the form goes off of.  However, when I created the form to see my students, I want to be able filter out just the particular class need and not all of my classes.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

You may find this described in the Microsoft Support article of:
[Enable users to find a record by selecting a value from a list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-users-to-find-a-record-by-selecting-a-value-from-a-list-e3ed7711-433a-4931-9cab-b0f71a90c329).

The article describes how to create a list box or a combo box that can be used
to find a record when a value is selected from the list, thus finding existing
records without having to type a value into the Find dialog box
(which is another possibility).

You will need to first create a query, as described in the article:
[Create a simple select query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-simple-select-query-de8b1c8d-14e9-4b25-8e22-70888d54de59).